# How do I display the current value in an edit form using haml custom inputs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

The code I'm working with is dynamically rendering the input fields in this edit form, like so:

```
%input.custom{:name => "short_form[#{field_name}]", :type => field_type, :id => field_id, :value => short_form.send(field_name)}
```

Based on the field_type value it renders a certain type of input field. However, I cannot get the value to display at all. The value attribute just ends up showing up as blank. Any suggestions? field_name is the attribute name btw, and short_form is the object (this is in a partial).

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
:value => short_form.object.send(field_name)
```